# Redis sentinel marks slaves as down

Tags: redis, master-slave, sentinel

I'm trying to setup a typical redis sentinel configuration, with three machines that will run three redis servers and three redis sentinels. The Master/Slave part of the redis servers are working OK, but the sentinels are not working. When I start two sentinels, the sentinel with the master detects the slaves, but mark them as down after the specified amount of time.  I'm running Redis 3.0.5 64-bit in debian jessie machines.

```
8319:X 22 Dec 14:06:17.855 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
8319:X 22 Dec 14:06:17.855 # Sentinel runid is   cdd5bbd5b84c876982dbca9d45ecc4bf8500e7a2
8319:X 22 Dec 14:06:17.855 # +monitor master mymaster xxxxxxxx0 6379 quorum 2
8319:X 22 Dec 14:06:18.857 * +slave slave xxxxxxxx2:6379 xxxxxxx2 6379 @ mymaster xxxxxxx0 6379
8319:X 22 Dec 14:06:18.858 * +slave slave xxxxxx1:6380 xxxxxxx1 6380 @ mymaster xxxxxxx0 6379
8319:X 22 Dec 14:07:18.862 # +sdown slave xxxxxxxx1:6380 xxxxxxx1 6380 @ mymaster xxxxxx0 6379
8319:X 22 Dec 14:07:18.862 # +sdown slave xxxxxx2:6379 xxxxxxx2    6379 @ mymaster xxxxxx0 6379
```

Sentinel config file:

```
daemonize yes
pidfile "/var/run/redis/redis-sentinel.pid"
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis-sentinel.log"
bind 127.0.0.1 xxxxxxx0
port 26379
sentinel monitor mymaster xxxxxxx0 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 60000
sentinel config-epoch mymaster 0
sentinel leader-epoch mymaster 0
dir "/var/lib/redis"
```

Of course, there is connectivity between these machines, as the slaves are working OK:

```
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.285 * Connecting to MASTER xxxxxxxx0:6379 <br/>
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.286 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started 
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.286 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.287 * Master replied to PING, replication can     continue...
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.288 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no   cached master)
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.291 * Full resync from master: f637ca8fe003acd09c6d021aed3f89a0d9994c9b:98290
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.350 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 18 bytes from master
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.350 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Flushing old data
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.350 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory
7553:S 22 Dec 13:46:33.350 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Finished with success
7553:S 22 Dec 14:01:33.072 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can answer myself. The problem was that the first IP that appeared in the sentinel conf was the localhost ip. It needs to be the binding IP. Just in case it serves anyone.

Comment: i.e. You cannot have `bind 127.0.0.1 123.123.123.123` but `bind 123.123.123.123 127.0.0.1` in your `sentinel.conf`. Thanks!